# OnClick/OnClientClick event with Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, onclientclick

I am a little confused to use this script and how it actually works?

Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                $('#various3').attr('href', $(this).val());
            });


                $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
                    setTimeout(showStickySuccessToast, 1000);
                    function showStickySuccessToast() {
                        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
                            text: 'Finished taking Screenshot!',
                            sticky: false,
                            position: 'middle-center',
                            type: 'success',
                            closeText: '',
                            close: function () {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                })                
        });
      </script>
```

This is my button:

```
<a id="various3" href="#"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="Button" OnClientClick="Button1_Click"/></a>
```

This is my code behind for button1_Click event:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NewTh As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoIT)
    NewTh.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
    NewTh.Start()
    ImgPreview.ImageUrl = "~/uploads/Sample.jpg"
End Sub
```

Now if I click the button it should open the iframe and display the message which I am able to do.
Now the problem is how do I call the button1_Click event which is in the codebehind at the same time. 
I have used `OnClick` and `OnClientClick` event as shown below but it's not working and I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got things backwards:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

The above example assumes that `Button1_Click` is the code-behind click event handler. Since you're assigning the client click event in jQuery, you shouldn't need to use `OnClientClick` at all.

**EDIT**

I would check to make sure that validation isn't intefering with the click. You can test this by setting `CausesValidation="false"` on the Button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply If I use OnClick it's not firing up the codebehind code.

Comment: Do you have a `Button1_Click` method in the code-behind? Is it marked `protected`? Have you recompiled?

Comment: Yes I have rebuild and I have a Button1_Click method and It is protected as shown in the above code.

Comment: @James-Thank you so much it worked now any specific reason for this?

Comment: You had validation somewhere that was preventing it from posting back.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

`Onclick` = raises a postback, executing the server eventhandler.

`OnClientClick` = raises a client click event and you can call a javascript function but you cant handlé an asp event directly although after calling a javascript function a postback occurs.